# Split a string and set the output into variables

Tags: php, sql

I would like to split a string and set the output into variables

```
$test = 1,2,3;
```

the value's are dynamic so they can change. Sometimes there are more values. So i would like to set the variables `$test1 $test2` etc.  Dynamically.
and i would like to get it like this:

```
$test1 = 1;
$test2 = 2;
$test3 = 3;
etc.
```

When i explode it i get an array. I would like to get it as strings back. So i can use it in a Where clause (not where in for an array because i already tried this with an array.)

Model(codeigniter):

```
function rapport_detail_kosten($idKlant){
            $this->db->from('Project');
                $this->db->join('Kosten', 'Kosten.idProject = Project.idProject');

if ($idKlant > 0){
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);}
         $query = $this->db->get();
    $project = array();
            foreach($query->result() as $row){
                $project[] = $row->idProject;
            }
    $hoi = implode(" ",$project); 
         $sum = 0;
 $this->db->select_sum('Prijs'); 
 $this->db->from('Kosten');
 $this->db->where_in('Kosten.idProject',$hoi);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 foreach ($query->result() as $row){
     $sum = $row->Prijs;
 }

        if($query->num_rows()>0){
            return $query->result();
             return($sum);
         }
        else{
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Comment: This is wrong method of work. 
You have to use array instead of creating multiple variables..

Comment: yeah but how can you split the array to run a where statement for each value in the array? And NOT where_in.

Comment: Rene there are a lot of options for that ;) but you have to show your sql code to get such answer..

Answer (score 8):

If `$test` is a string:

```
$test = explode(',', '1,2,3');
```

Then:

```
list($test1, $test2, $test3) = $test;
```

or:

```
foreach ($test as $value) {
  ${'test' . $value} = $value;
}
```

Comment: @DushyantJoshi case with `list` works only for limited amount - you have to declare output variables.

Comment: So the second case seems more convincing :)

Comment: The second way is better, but perhaps using the value as part of the variable name isn't good idea, instead there can be set the $key + 1 to skip 0...

Comment: it is better to use numeric counter instead of using $value to avoid special chars

Answer (score 1):

Same as @hsz answer but with one difference..

```
foreach ($test as $key=>$value) {
   // +1 because 1st array key is 0 
   ${'test' . ($key+1)} = $value;
}
```

or with counter

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($test as $value) {
   ${'test' . $i++} = $value;
}
```

But it all depends on what you really need.. 
Once you have your values in 1 array you can use them a lot easier then creating such variables..

.. For the SQL please check my edit

```
function rapport_detail_kosten($idKlant){
    $this->db->from('Project');
    $this->db->join('Kosten', 'Kosten.idProject = Project.idProject');

    if ($idKlant > 0){
        $this->db->where('idKlant', $idKlant);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $project = array();
    foreach($query->result() as $row){
        $project[] = $row->idProject;
    }
    $sum = 0;
    $this->db->select('Kosten.idProject, SUM(Kosten.idProject) as sum'); 
    $this->db->from('Kosten');
    $this->db->where_in('Kosten.idProject',$project);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What i would like to do is return multiple $sums. When there are multiple $project. for example $project = 1,2,3 . $sum needs to have an output that looks something like this $sum 0,80,1

Comment: So for each $project there needs to be a different select_sum

Comment: @Rene can you check the result from this query :) it should be result object with elements containing ID and SUM

Comment: it results in one return. one id and one SUM. The other ones are undefined

Comment: it returns the SUM of Lowest idKosten with the Joined idProject

Comment: Do you have sql caching at your project? perhaps you need to set
$this->db->flush_cache(); between your 2 queries (replace the $sum=0 with it)

Comment: it still return one id and one SUM when i have MULTIPLE values as the $project. I would like to make a SUM for each $project. And not for all ids in the array $project. Hope i made myself a bit more clear now:)

Answer (score 0):

```
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($test as $value) {
      $count++
      ${'test' . $count} = $value;
    }
```